Formula Field Creation to return specific values
I am trying to create a formula field on "Cost Center" object with Return Type:Text values.
Please find the following:
if (BXTR_LegalEntity_r.BXTR_LegalEntityCode_c == 01024, 07500, 07501, 07505, 07570) return 'Vantive' Else 'Baxter'
But, i am not clear with which field do i need to assign 'Vantive' else 'Baxter' values?
So, can someone help me to sove this one?
Thanks,
Rudraswamy

Formulas appear as a read-only field. You do not "assign" the value to another field. Your formula should look like this:
CASE(BXTR_LegalEntity_r.BXTR_LegalEntityCode_c,
'01024', 'Vantive',
'07500', 'Vantive',
'07501', 'Vantive',
'07505', 'Vantive',
'07570', 'Vantive',
'Baxter'
)


Thank you so much. @sfdcfox
